# Refactor to meet mypy requirements

Tags: python, refactoring, mypy

I have a codebase which I would like to validate using mypy. In the current design, it is very common that a class may have a non-primitive member that can be set later after `__init__`.

So, in `__init__` the member is initialized to `None` and its type becomes `Optional` accordingly.

The problem is that now `MyPy` requires me to check that the member is not `None` every time it is being used.

As a quick solution I can add `assert self._member is not None  # MyPy` in all the relevant scopes, but it seems like a very bad practice.

Another idea would be to add a `@property` and do the assertion inside, but this also seems like a huge overhead.

Is there a more natural/correct design that can overcome this issue?

**Edit:**

To clarify, my code is fully type annotated.

The member definition is `self._member: Optional[MemberType]`.

Comment: Not sure about mypy, but typing it at class level might help: `class Foo: bar: SomeType`

Answer (score 3):

If an instance variable is assigned outside of `__init__`, then an instance of the class may be in a state where the variable is not set. And to be honest, this should be taken into account in the functions using it. But if we believe or ensure that these functions will not be called in this state, then we can annotate this instance member as follows:

```
class Foo:
    var_1: int  # variant 1

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.var_2: int  # variant 2
```

These statements do not create real variables, *only [annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements)* of instance variables that will be taken into account by the `mypy`

Comment: I agree that the `None` case should be taken into account. Ideally I would like to verify it once in API calls and have the rest of the (helper) functions use preconditions. Regarding your suggestion for `var_2` this is very interesting. I didn't know I can define members without an inital value. Might just be the solution.

Comment: Correction, I checked and it seems that defining without an initial value does not really define anything.