# Class variables declared but not instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-typing

I'm trying to understand the following Python code

```
class MyClass():
    aa:int
```

What is happening here? It seems to me that the variable `aa` is a class variable which is declared but not initialized. The `:int` seems to be a typing hint. Am I correct? I can instantiate the class but I cannot access `aa`. Which makes me think that my understanding is wrong. See below

```
 mm = MyClass()
 mm.aa
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-cfce603dd5e0>", line 1, in <module>
    mm.aa

AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'aa'
```

Comment: What is exactly the version of Python you are using?

Comment: Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462506/13782669

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this only creates an [*annotation*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-annotation) for the attribute, it does not create the attribute itself. Attributes and variables are only created by assignment, and nothing's being assigned here, so it doesn't exist (not even with an implicit `None` or such).

This pattern is useful to satisfy type checkers if the attribute is initialised outside of `__init__`, e.g.:

```
class MyClass(SomeParentClass):
    aa: int

    def initialize(self):
        self.aa = 'foo'
```

Let's say that `SomeParentClass` will call `initialize` at some defined point during its instantiation process and it wants subclasses to use `initialize` to do their initialisations, instead of overriding `__init__`. A type checker might complain here that `aa` is created outside of `__init__` and is therefore not safe to access. The `aa: int` annotation explicitly says that `aa` should be expected to exist as an `int` at any time, so is safe to access (taking care that that'll actually be the case is *your* responsibility then). An example of this kind of pattern can be found in [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize), for instance.

Another use of these annotations of course are classes where those annotations are explicitly used at runtime, like Python's own [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) do.